# Rails: set locale for a specific path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, locale

I want to specify locale for specific path.

in my whole application I have my default local e set to :es

```
 config.i18n.default_locale = :es
```

That works in the normal fashion for the whole application, I want to know how can I specify a specific locale for a set of paths...

I integrated a third party application called [maily_herald](https://github.com/Sology/maily_herald-webui), in order to make it's paths available for my application i have to add this line to my routes.rb file

```
mount MailyHerald::Webui::Engine => "/maily_webui"
```

the problem is that there are not translations for locale :es, so it does not work properly... I want to let all the paths under `/maily_webui` to have locale :en so the third party application will work in english while my application will still work in :es

any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  .....
  before_filter :set_locale


  def set_locale
    if request.fullpath == "some_path"
      I18n.locale = :some_locale
    else
      I18n.locale = params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
    end
  end

end
```